# Data logging with rosbag in rosjava

Tags: ros, rosbag, rosjava, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currrently using rosjava to create an control interface on my tablet to control a robot. Everything works fine except that rosbag does not record information from the nodes created by rosjava.

May I know if this logging feature has been supported for rosjava? If yes then how to enable it? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11976/data-logging-with-rosbag-in-rosjava/) by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-11-22**:
Are you setting the host correctly in the NodeConfiguration? Can you provide some sample code?

**Comment by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on 2011-11-22**:
I am sending command velocity to drive the robot from a Motorola Xoom tablet. The command velocity sent from the tablet was not recorded properly while that sent from the robot machine itself could be seen in the bag file. I am using the rosjava version from source as of July 2011.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-11-19**:
What information isn't being recorded exactly? Are you using the latest rosjava from source or the released binary version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible that this is due to the way that rosbag subscribes (i.e. using wildcards). Support for that was added more recently. You may need to update to the latest rosjava.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-11-25**:
Added bug ticket for rosjava, pending confirmation: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=71

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-11-25**:
Oops, just noticed that it looks like rosjava isn't providing the right connection information.  The provided message definition seems to be always empty "".  This results in an md5 of d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2011-11-25**:
I can confirm that prior to the latest update (Rosjava Android from late October), rosbag record was broken.  I updated to the latest version (~Nov 17), and this is now fixed.  If you have this problem, be sure you're running the latest rosjava from source.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-31**:
Hi, which version of rosjava_android, rosjava_core and appmanadroid are you using? we are using appamnandroid: hg update 7adc52c0e5f0,
rosjava_android:  hg update 6cf45d11853f
rosjava_core: hg update ca6ecfeba48b
as described in http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android